# Jetpack compose: How to make two columns equals height

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

There are one row and two columns in it, the left column has two subrows and the right has there.

[image]

here is my code:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun TwoColumns() {
        Row {
            BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 2, rows = 2, Color.Blue)
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
            BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 3, rows = 3, Color.Cyan)
        }
    }

    @Composable
    fun BottomLeftLetterKey(columns: Int, rows: Int, color: Color) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.background(color)) {
            repeat(columns) {
                Row {
                    repeat(rows) {
                        ElevatedButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                            shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                            colors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(containerColor = Color.Green, contentColor = Color.Red),
                            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
                        ) {
                            Text(text = "2")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I want the two columns are the same height. That is the blue column should be the same height as the cyan column.

I tried to set:
`Column(modifier = Modifier.background(color).fillMaxHeight())`

Then it's too height what what I want.

[image]

Any tips? thanks!

**EDIT**

`modifier = modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min/Max)` is the right direction. But confused which option `Min` or `Max` is the right one? I tried both are the same effect.

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements#intrinsics-in-action):

> The Row composable's minIntrinsicHeight will be the maximum minIntrinsicHeight of its children.

seems `IntrinsicSize.Min` is the right one rather than `IntrinsicSize.Max`.

Comment: `Then it's too height what what I want` show how it looks then?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Attached like above thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to apply `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` to the `Row` and the `fillMaxHeight()` modifier to the `Column`s.

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 2, rows = 2, Color.Blue)
    BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 3, rows = 3, Color.Cyan)
}


@Composable
fun BottomLeftLetterKey(columns: Int, rows: Int, color: Color) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxHeight()  //<--- fill max height
        .background(color)
    ) {
        //....
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: should it be `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)` to get the children's max height?

Comment: From the example of android doc `The Row composable's minIntrinsicHeight will be the maximum minIntrinsicHeight of its children.`  set `Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` should be the right one, a bit confused, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Question**

> I want the two columns are the same height. That is the blue column
> should be the same height as the cyan column.

**Answer**

If you simply want to match the height of the two columns, you can apply intrinsic size to the parent `Row`.

**Try it**

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TwoColumns() {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Max)) {
        BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 2, rows = 2, color = Color.Blue)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 3, rows = 3, color = Color.Cyan)
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomLeftLetterKey(
    columns: Int,
    rows: Int,
    color: Color
) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .background(color)
    ) {
        repeat(columns) {
            Row {
                repeat(rows) {
                    Button(
                        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Preview**
[image: preview]

**Short description**

`Row` in `TwoColumns` Composable maxheight will be the the max height of it’s children. - `BottomLeftLetterKey(Blue), Spacer, BottomLeftLetterKey(Cyan)`

**Ref**

- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements

Comment: from the doc seems `modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)` should be the right one.

Comment: @WilliamHu It depends on your needs. if you need set children of row(`columns`) height to maximum minIntrinsicHeight, use `IntrinsicSize.Min`. I described setting column height to maximum maxIntrinsicHeight. In your case, the result of the two IntrinsicSize modifiers is the same because children with the same intrinsic size min and max values.

Answer (score 0):

o make the two columns equal in height, you can use the align modifier with Alignment.Top inside the Row composable. This will align the columns at the top, making them equal in height.

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TwoColumns() {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top
    ) {
        BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 2, rows = 2, Color.Blue)
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        BottomLeftLetterKey(columns = 3, rows = 3, Color.Cyan)
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomLeftLetterKey(columns: Int, rows: Int, color: Color) {
    Column(modifier = Modifier.background(color)) {
        repeat(columns) {
            Row {
                repeat(rows) {
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp),
                        colors = ButtonDefaults.elevatedButtonColors(
                            containerColor = Color.Green,
                            contentColor = Color.Red
                        ),
                        contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text(text = "2")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```